# Transpose Row Counts over Columns on SQL Query

Tags: sql, aggregation-framework, pivot, transpose

I'm wondering if someone more adept at the SQL Pivot function could help me out. This is pretty basic, but for some reason I'm drawing a blank here.

I have the following script that gets error codes on a particular date:

```
SELECT GETDATE() as "Date"
,ErrorCode
FROM Application
```

This returns results like this.

| Date | ErrorCode |
| --- | --- |
| 3/16/2023 | Code1 |
| 3/16/2023 | Code1 |
| 3/16/2023 | Code2 |
| 3/16/2023 | Code2 |
| 3/16/2023 | Code3 |
| 3/16/2023 | Code3 |
| 3/16/2023 | Code4 |
| 3/16/2023 | Code4 |

However, I just need the total count of each error code on that date, so I need it to return this:

| Date | Code1 | Code2 | Code3 | Code4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/16/2023 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

Anyone have any clue on how to use PIVOT for this? Or is there another solution I'm not thinking of?

Really appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what RDBMS you're using. This is in SQL Server.

[Dynamic pivot Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/v2e_vqcr)

Step one is to create a variable with your 'column names' in it. Once pivoted, your column names will be the values in your ErrorCode column.

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

  WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT ErrorCode FROM temp)
SELECT @columns += QUOTENAME(ErrorCode) +',' 
  FROM cte 
 ORDER BY ErrorCode
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns)-1);
```

Using your sample data, @columns will equal

```
[Code1],[Code2],[Code3],[Code4]
```

Next we build the pivot inside of another variable. Since we only have the two columns, I used _date twice. The first _Date is to group the dates in the pivot, DateCount is the value we count, and errorCode is the category we pivot on.

(*side note: don't use Date as a column name. Date is a reserved word and calling it in a query can cause issues.*)

```
DECLARE @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
  
SET @sql = '
SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT _Date 
       , _Date DateCount
       , ErrorCode
    FROM temp
) src
PIVOT
( COUNT(DateCount) FOR ErrorCode
    IN ('+ @columns +')
)pvt;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

Result:

| _Date | Code1 | Code2 | Code3 | Code4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-16 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

Comment: I’m using SQL Server, so this is a huge help! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.DATE,
SUM
(
  CASE 
    WHEN C.ERRORCODE='Code1' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
)CODE_1,
SUM
(
 CASE 
   WHEN C.ERRORCODE='Code2' THEN 1
   ELSE 0
  END
)CODE_2,
SUM
(
 CASE 
   WHEN C.ERRORCODE='Code3' THEN 1
   ELSE 0
  END
)CODE_3,
SUM
(
  CASE 
  WHEN C.ERRORCODE='Code4' THEN 1
   ELSE 0
  END
)CODE_4
FROM YOUR_TABLE AS C
GROUP BY C.DATE
```

You can try this approach. If you want to say "I do not know how many codes I have" then please google "dynamic pivot"

Comment: Yep, there’s tons of codes and that query was really simplified just to explain the general goal. 

Dynamic pivot it is! Thanks for helping me get started.